# OUTER JOIN not working as expected

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, join, outer-join

So I know this has been done to death but I can't find the exact answer I need so am also happy to hear about alternatives on how to do this.

IN SQL Server 2008R2
I Have a client ID, Year, Month & Revenue, AND I am doing a Full Outer Join because I want to produce something that lookis like this:

```
Client_ID , Year, Month Revenue, Prev_Year, Prev_Month. Prev_Revenue.
5003        2011  12    100      2010       12          50
5003        2012  12    120      2011       12         100
```

The Code I used is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Sales.fin_year
  ,sales.fin_qtr
 ,sales.fin_Half
 ,sales.fin_month    
 ,Sum(sales.rev) AS Rev
 ,Sales.client_name
  ,sales.client_id,
  prev.fin_year AS Prev_Fin_Year
 ,prev.fin_qtr AS Prev_Fin_Qtr
 ,prev.fin_Half AS Prev_Fin_Half
 ,prev.fin_month AS Prev_Fin_Month,
  Sum(prev.rev) AS prev_Rev
FROM Thisismytable Sales
FULL OUTER JOIN
  Thisismytable PREV
   ON PREV.fin_year = DATEADD(Y,-1,sales.fin_year)
   AND prev.fin_qtr = sales.fin_qtr
   AND prev.fin_half = sales.fin_half
   AND (prev.fin_month = sales.fin_month)
   AND PREV.client_id = Sales.client_id
```

What I get is a table that displays 2011 data and previous 2010 Values (Where the months match)
But when I look at 2012 the previous data only exists for when the same month transaction was done in 2011 e.g

```
January 2011 = Revenue of $20
January 2012 = Previous revenue of $20
```

The problem is, that if a value exists for 2011, It won't appear at all in the 2012 data.
I need something that does this:

```
January 2012 = 100                  Previous Rev =20
```

### February 2012 = NULL (No February data exists at all for 2012)  Previous Rev = 500                      (For         Feb 2011)

Now, the reason that I have the months matching is that if I join on the year, the half year or Qtr, all my data duplicates in the previous column. What I'm looking for is If the data matches, then show the year vs previous year revenue, If it exists in year, but not previous year, show null prev_rev, and vice versa.

Hope someone can help :)
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to steer you towards the right(imho) direction with your problem.
I would first try and create a table/view which contains a list of clientIds and dates you want to show.
So if you want to report at least per month you will need 1 record per client/month.
For simpleness i'm assuming this view/table is created and is called NewTimeTableClient.
From there on you can do 2 outer joins to fetch the data for last and current year.
I also assume you'll need some group by's to accomodate the sum's(otherwise your sum will only be the sum of 1 record in the sales table).
The outcome would look something like this , i hope it gets you started.
Not that there is no distinct(not a fan of using distinct ;) ) :

```
SELECT 
  ttc.client_name
 ,ttc.client_id,
 ,ttc.fin_year
 ,ttc.fin_qtr
 ,ttc.fin_Half
 ,ttc.fin_month    
 ,Sum(CURR.rev) AS RevCurr 
 ,DATEADD(y,-11,ttc.fin_year) AS Prev_Fin_Year
  Sum(prev.rev) AS prev_Rev
FROM NewTimeTableClient ttc
LEFT OUTER JOIN Thisismytable PREV
   ON PREV.fin_year = DATEADD(Y,-1,ttc.fin_year)
   AND prev.fin_qtr = ttc.fin_qtr
   AND prev.fin_half = ttc.fin_half
   AND (prev.fin_month = ttc.fin_month)
   AND PREV.client_id = ttc.client_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN Thisismytable CURR
   ON CURR.fin_year = ttc.fin_year)
   AND CURR.fin_qtr = ttc.fin_qtr
   AND CURR.fin_half = ttc.fin_half
   AND (CURR.fin_month = ttc.fin_month)
   AND CURR.client_id = ttc.client_id
GROUP BY ttc.client_name
 ,ttc.client_id,
 ,ttc.fin_year
 ,ttc.fin_qtr
 ,ttc.fin_Half
 ,ttc.fin_month
```

Comment: Thanks for that but I still get the same issue Where if the data for Say January existed in 2011 but there was no transaction for January in 2012, I still want a row to appear in 2012. In essence what I am trying to create is a report that can rollup so that the current revenue matches 2012, and the previous revenue matches to 2011, and then create % difference.

Comment: if your ttc table has a record clientId X year 2012 month 1 then that record will show up after you do 2 left outer joins. Could you elaborate how you implemented the NewTimeTableClient ttc table or provide example data?

Comment: Actually I missed out on some of the dates so it wasn't working as expected. you're solution hit it right on the mark first time :) Thank you so much for that :)

Comment: Nice, no problem ! Feel free to mark my answer as the solution btw